# What is wrong with my insertion sort code?

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement  this code in my android app, the list of petrol stations is supposed to be sorted in ascending order.
Should i implement another sort method instead?
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class sortTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Float> arr   = new ArrayList<Float> ();
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 12 ; i++)
    {
    arr.add(i, (float) (((Math.random() * 90) + 10)/10)); // add random values to array 
    }

    ArrayList<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataHeader.add("Shell distance: "+ arr.get(0));
    listDataHeader.add("Esso  Distance:" +arr.get(1));
    listDataHeader.add("Tesco Distance "+arr.get(2));
    listDataHeader.add("Asda Distance "+arr.get(3));
    listDataHeader.add("BP Distance "+arr.get(4));
    listDataHeader.add("Texaco Distance "+arr.get(5));


    String temp;
    int f = listDataHeader.size();
    for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
      for(int j=i+1;j<f;j++){
        if(arr.get(i)>arr.get(j)){
          temp = listDataHeader.get(i);
          String x = listDataHeader.get(j);
          listDataHeader.set(i,listDataHeader.get(j));
          listDataHeader.set(j,temp);
         }
      }

    }
    for(String str:listDataHeader) //this list is list<String>
      {
      System.out.println(str);
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Use collection.sort(list);

Comment: Can you tell us what problem do you have? some output maybe?

Comment: This is not insertion sort, but isn’t valid bubble sort either. You are looking into one array, modifying another list and then again looking into the array which does not reflect the modification you made to the list.

Comment: Example of the output:
Texaco Distance 1.9050133
Esso  Distance:1.7805898
BP Distance 2.681449
Tesco Distance 8.506616
Asda Distance 1.6738975
Shell distance: 6.0956526

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is bubble-sort, not insertion-sort. Also, did you know there is already a `Collections.sort()` method ?

Anyway, the reason why it doesn't work is because you have two different lists You are sorting one and making comparisons on the other (you are swapping the elements of `listDataHeader` but your tests go on the list `arr`).

My recommendation: keep only one list for swapping and comparing: use `arr`. After it is sorted, format it adding the names of the petrol stations and pass it to the other list: `listDataHeader`.

But if you want to keep it as it is, you can swap `arr` at the same time you are swapping `listDataHeader` and that will work.

**Another solution that requires more work:**

You can create your own `Petrol` class that implements the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. This class can have 2 elements: a `String` with the petrol's name and a `float` that is your random value on which you are going to sort.

Now you  can create a `List` and put all your `Petrol`s in there, then you just call  [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
 on that list and it will work.

There are plenty of examples out there, about how to implement `Comparable` and even some in The Java Tutorial.

Nice part: if you do it this way you will grasp ore knowledge about how things in Java are extended.

Comment: how can I implement the Collections.sort() method?

Comment: It is a static method on the `Collections` class, you just call it with your list as a parameter. Have a look at the Java Tutorial for sample code and more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html

Comment: I can do the Collections.sort(arr); and print out the sorted list, but it would only be a sorted list for the generated numbers. How can I implement this to add the listDataHeader?

Comment: You either use the second approach I suggested, or the 3rd one, which I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes a few unnecessary calls (String x gets assigned and not used at all), and is not an insertion sort as well. Insertion sort in this case would be:

```
    int f = listDataHeader.size();
    for(int i=0; i<f; i++){    //first prediction: the smallest element in iteration is at "i".
        int prediction = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<f; j++){
            if(arr.get(i) > arr.get(j)){    //found even smaller element - change prediction.
                prediction = j
            }
         }
         String temp = listDataHeader.get(i);
         listDataHeader.set(i, listDataHeader.get(prediction);
         listDataHeader.set(j, temp);
         arr.set(j, arr.get(i));            //for this to work you need to sort the array of
         arr.set(i, arr.get(prediction));   //values as well.

      }
```

Your current algorithm is doing bubble-sort and not in an usual way (with do-while loop). You may also improve the code I write by checking if prediction != i. if not, swapping is not necessary. Read a bit more about simple sorting algorithms.

Comment: i tried your solution but i gives the smallest value, followed by the values for the "shell" listDataHeader i.e
Texaco Distance 4.2378345
Shell distance: 9.244002
Shell distance: 9.244002
Shell distance: 9.244002
Shell distance: 9.244002
Shell distance: 9.244002